# SR-ORG:8369: _MI_0 - What coordinate system is it?

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

I have a TAB file with strange coordinate system.
QGIS shows coordinate system as unnamed:

[image]

But places objects in the correct place on the map.

FME (2023 version) recognizes it as _MI_0.

[image]

I have found here https://spatialreference.org/ref/?page=90 that it is SR-ORG:8369: _MI_0

But can't find any other information about it.

FME 2020 version identify it is LL-84. Why it is in meters then?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/_mi_0/.

Comment: That spatial reference is "user-contributed" and I'm not sure it's particularly helpful. _MI_0 means FME doesn't recognize it, so the parameters listed on that page will be for one person's particular scenario. They will be different for the user posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what coordinate system it should be? I think the simple problem is that FME doesn't recognize it. _MI_0 is just a temporary coordinate system.

Take a look in the FME log window for lines like this:

```
FME Configuration: Source coordinate system for reader MAPINFO_1[MAPINFO] set to `UTM83-10' as read from input data
Coordinate System `UTM83-10' parameters: CS_NAME=`UTM83-10' DESC_NM=`UTM with NAD83 datum, Zone 10, Meter; .....
```

That will help you determine how FME sees this. Also look for messages like:

```
WARN: Datum definition XYZ does not exist
```

...because I suspect that there is one particular aspect of this data that is causing the problem (maybe the datum, maybe another component).

*Edit to add: Also (in the Data Inspector) click on the coordinate system link in the Feature Information Window and it will tell you the definition.*

If it's an actual, recognized coordinate system, and FME doesn't recognize it, then we can make a fix. If it's more of a local coordinate system for a particular project, then it might help to make a custom coordinate system in FME to handle it.

If this doesn't help, maybe you can [create a support case with Safe](https://community.safe.com/s/submit-case)? Include the dataset and they will be able to diagnose the problem pretty quickly.

**Edits**

OK, it looks like you know what it should be. So, firstly you could try the CoordinateSystemSetter transformer to set it to EPSG:3414. I believe that should work. No reprojection needed. It should be in those coordinates already.

Alternatively, the coordinate system is definitely part of FME, so it looks like we're just missing a mapping somewhere. You can add that in manually so FME recognizes it.

- Browse to reproject then exceptions in your FME installation folder.

  C:\Program Files\FME2023\Reproject\Exceptions
- Open the file mapinfo.db in a text editor.
- Add in a line with the Mapinfo definition of this coordinate system

From what I can tell, you need to add:

```
MAPINFO|SVY21|8,104,m,103.83333333,1.36666667,1,28001.642,38744.572
```

The MAPINFO part is what FME needs to know it belongs to MapInfo. The SVY21 is the coordinate system we want to map to (equivalent to EPSG 3414), and the rest are the parameters for MapInfo. The parameters above are what I found in this [document online](https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/stratus/mapinfo_stratus_uploader_guide/en/supported%20projections.pdf), but I suggest you double-check them before relying on them.

If you want this coordinate mapping added to FME officially, then you should make that request through the support team using the above link.

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Yes, it supposed to be epsg:3414. I've tested, that if data is in Postgis - then FME recognize it correctly as 3414. When I export data from Posrgis to TABs, then it sees it as _MI_0. Even if I additionally add Reprojector transformer or set epsg:3414 in the Reader in any case Writer gets _MI_0.

Comment: OK. Check out the edit I made to my answer. That should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! CoordinateSystemSetter transformer doesn't resolve. I will create a ticket to Safe.

Comment: Created ticket and received a file to add in Documents\FME\CoordinateSystemExceptions with exactly the same content you adviced above. Now FME recognizes SVY21, not _MI_0. Thanks!