# TAB file can't be saved in EPSG:3414 using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, tab, singapore

In QGIS 3.22.8 I am trying to convert the file from SHP to TAB. Shapefile has clearly defined CRS: EPSG:3414 - SVY21 / Singapore TM.

[image]

When I save it as TAB (CRS defined as well):

[image]

I am getting a TAB file with an unnamed CRS:

[image]

How to overcome this? I believe this causing me a problem in further data processing in another application.

Comment: Is there a connection with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468240/sr-org8369-mi-0-what-coordinate-system-is-it? Have you experienced problems with those MapInfo files? If you want interoperability I would have a try with GeoPackage. MapInfo reads the format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS is using GDAL for dealing with the MapInfo data. MapInfo has a little special way for handling the coordinate systems. GDAL maps the CRS definitions into native MapInfo syntax as well as it can. For datums the mapping parameters are defined in this file https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/mitab/mitab_spatialref.cpp.

EPSG:3414 is using these definitions in the EPSG registry

```
WKT2:2019 string:
PROJCRS["SVY21 / Singapore TM",
    BASEGEOGCRS["SVY21",
        DATUM["SVY21",
    ...
```

There is not any entry for SVY21 in the current mitab_spatialref.cpp. Therefore GDAL creates an unnamed CRS. Most probably the parameters are right and MapInfo can place the data into correct place even the name of the CRS is missing.

You can write mail into gdal-dev mailing list and ask if the SVY21 datum could be added into the mitab sources. It would help a lot if you could provide some native test data from MapInfo. Save one feature into both .tab and MIF/MID formats in EPSG:3414.

**EDIT**

I found this information about a new coordinate system that is probably missing from GDAL https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/mapinfo-pro/v2021/en-us/pdf/mapinfo-pro-v2021-user-guide.pdf (MapInfo 11.0)

> Singapore Coordinate Systems
>
> We have added new Singapore coordinate systems:
>
> • "SVY21 Transverse
> Mercator System", 8, 104, 7, 103.83333333, 1.36666667, 1, 28001.642,
> 38744.572

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand what's going on. Do you mean this mailing list gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org? If I send anything there it will come to all subscribers, I afraid. Is that allowed?

Comment: That is the correct list. Your mail will go to all subscribers, that's how mailing lists work. It is certainly allowed. Gdal-dev list is also for GDAL users and by asking your question the other users can learn from your problem.

Comment: User @user1641 is Peter Horborst Moller from Precisely. Maybe he can tell something else about it.

Comment: @user30184, thx! saw you edits. So CRS was added to MapInfo. But is missing in QGIS. I will try to write to gdal mailing list.

Comment: The new coordinate system was added into MapInfo, the proprietary software by Precisely. QGIS and GDAL deal with MapInfo file formats through the open source MITAB library (very outdated info page http://mitab.maptools.org/) and that does not know the new system yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded some buildings from OSM in Fernvale Glades Area in Singapore:

[image]

The temporary layer's CRS is in: EPSG4326 - WGS84

[image]

I try then to export my temporary data to TAB format

[image]

[image]

Use EPSG:3414 .

[image]

The result is the same as yours:

[image]

If we use another CRS EPSG:3857, we do not have the same issue:

[image]

If checked with FME, the EPSG mentioned is 7030 .

However, if tested with shapefile, the CRS is correct:

[image]

When assigned the EPSG:3414 to the layer, it does that well:

[image]

I suggest you try to open the tab file in MapInfo to test it out or use another format such as shapefile or even Geopackage in QGIS which does not have this issue:

[image]